# Java : Externalize JSON processing outside of code

Tags: java, json

I am writing an API, which accepts a JSON string from multiple providers

It will receive JSON with different structure, and it will be parsed to fetch some information and saved to an Object

The problem here is, the API can receive any JSON structure, so I can't hard code parsing logic.

I can detect which provider it came from, so is there any way to seed JSON parsing/transformation logic at runtime based on the provider?

Comment: Each structure is well know per provider? You can use something like MapStruct to parse/transform. Not sure if it fits. https://mapstruct.org/. Also if you use Jackson can transform you json into Java objects (example: https://www.javaguides.net/2019/04/how-to-read-write-json-using-jackson-jsonparser-and-jsongenerator.html).

Comment: Actually provider also can be added at runtime, so we cannot pre define parsing per provider